# please help me understand this jQuery selector

Tags: jquery

```
var dialogDiv = $('<div style="display:none;"></div>').appendTo('body');

$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form', dialogDiv));
```

"$('form', dialogDiv)", I know this should be jquery selector .  but if this is multiple selector.  should we move the dialogDiv inside the quote?  "$('form, dialogDiv')"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of jQuery's selector is [`context`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)
`$('form', dialogDiv)` is the same as `$(dialogDiv).find('form')`;

Answer (score 2):

Its looking for a `form` inside `divDialog` which appears to be empty.

Answer (score 1):

It is the equivalent of `$(dialogFiv).find('form')`.